# Reading value from JSON

Tags: json, angular, http, ionic-framework, ionic3

[image]

I have file of tips that I want to print. Every pressing on the button the next tip will print from the json file.
So I wrote a function, but right to now the reading from the file doesn't stop (attaching image of the log). 
Any idea to get this information? 
Thank you!

The function .**ts**:

```
tips: any;

 getDataJSON() {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.http.get('/assets/advices.json') 
          .subscribe((data) => {
            resolve(data);
            console.log(data);
           this.getDataJSON().then(data => {
              this.tips = data;
          }, err => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      });
    })
  }
```

**html**:

```
<button ion-button block (click)="getDataJSON()">Fetch External Data</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making nested calls which is not necessary

```
getDataJSON() {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.http.get('/assets/advices.json') 
          .subscribe((data) => {
            resolve(data);
            console.log(data);
          }, err => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      });
    })
  }
```